# Transferring files with line breaks in file names on Linux server

Tags: rhel, filenames, scp

A few files on my server were inadvertently saved with line breaks. They show up as `file?name.txt` when looking at the files on the server. Using scp to transfer these files to my local machine doesn't work, as I get a "couldn't write file" error. The error causing this has been fixed but I'm not able to access these files. What is the best way to get to these files?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to rename these files so that they don't have the line breaks in them? Are there existing files (without line breaks in their name) that would be clobbered as a result? (e.g. `filename.txt` from your example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newline is as valid as any other character in a file name on Unix. For a shell, that character has a special meaning (it separates commands), so needs to be quoted like any other special characters (like space, `;`, `|`...).

In Bourne-like shells, that can be done with single or double quotes:

```
ls -d 'a
b'
```

Or:

```
ls -d "a
b"
```

Some shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, FreeBSD `sh` at least) also support:

```
ls -d $'a\nb'
```

For `scp`, note that the name of the file is passed to the login shell of the remote user. When you do:

```
scp file user@host:something
```

it ends up invoking the user's login shell on `host` to interpret the:

```
scp -t something
```

command line (at least with openssh). So if that shell is Bourne-like, it has to be:

```
scp 'src/a
b' user@host:"dest/'a
b'"
```

If you do:

```
scp 'a
b' user@host:dest/
```

or

```
scp -r src user@host:dest/
```

sshd on the server runs:

```
scp -t dest/
```

or

```
scp -r -t dest/
```

And the names of the files are not passed on the remote shell command line, but embedded in the data stream between the client  and server `scp`. What I find however (with openssh  7.2p2 at least) is that the newline character ends up transformed to `\^J` (3 characters).

So you may want to use a different mechanism over `ssh` that transfers files more reliably like `rsync` or `sftp`, or `tar`:

```
tar cf - src | gzip | ssh user@host 'cd dest && gunzip | tar xpf -'
```

That would also deal better with preserving hard links, soft links and other file attribute. You may also need to consider charset conversion if the file names contain non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Ok I got it working -- rsync worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To rename existing files that have newlines (assuming that's what they are) in them, with `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash` or `mksh`:

```
for f in *$'\n'*; do mv -i -- "$f" "${f//$'\n'/}"; done
```

The glob pattern `*$'\n'*` says to match any/all filenames that have newlines in them; the `mv` command renames the files by removing all instances of newlines from them.